# Regex capture group not working as expected

Tags: regex, capture-group

I am trying to extract a info called "número de controle de cadeira cativa do Maracanã" (Maracanã's captive chair control number) from lawsuits using this regex:

```
cadeiras?\s*?(perpétua|cativa)?s?\s*?(de|com|,)?\s*?(o)?\s*?(número)?\s*?(de)?\s*?(controle)?\s*?(inicial)?\s*?(de)?\s*?(números?|nº)?\s*?(?<NUMERO_CONTROLE_CADEIRA>\d(\d|\s|-|–)+)\s*?(e)?\s*?\g<NUMERO_CONTROLE_CADEIRA>
```

The problem is that in cases where two control numbers appears separed by " e " (and in pt-br), even using \g subroutine, the second number is not beign captured:

> O Autor é detentor do direito de uso de duas cadeiras perpétuas com o
> número de controle nº 1234-123456789 e 3421 – 11111111 (Doc. 04) do
> Estádio

**NUMERO_CONTROLE_CADEIRA**: 1234-123456789

Not only that, in some cases, the group value is incomplete (the last number is out):

> O Autor é detentor do direito de uso de uma cadeira perpétua com o
> número de controle nº 4321-112223333 (Doc. 07) do Estádio Jornalista
> Mário Filho

**NUMERO_CONTROLE_CADEIRA**: 4321-11222333

I have more cases here: https://regex101.com/r/MxTAnZ/1

How can I fix this regex to get correctly these control numbers?

Comment: Your pattern is matching the first number, and then trying to match the captured number again. However, your input contains 2 different numbers. Trying to match `\g<NUMERO_CONTROLE_CADEIRA>` will only match what that group initially captured; it won't try to match the same regex pattern again.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you gave some explicit examples - the string and the desired capture. in any case, i may be *way* off, but how about something like: `.*número de controle.*? (?<NUMERO_CONTROLE_CADEIRA>[\d\-e –nº.]+)`?

Comment: @Yarin_007 https://regex101.com/r/SPmTPv/1

Comment: Yeah I saw that, but what are you looking to isolate? i.e. - `1.  O Autor é detentor do direito de uso de duas cadeiras perpétuas com o número de controle nº 1234-123456789 e 3421 – 11111111 (Doc. 04) do Estádio` -> `1234-1234567893421 – 11111111`. and `cadeira perpétua com o número de controle nº 1234` -> `1234`? is cadeiras part of it? should it have been `nº 1234 nº23 e nº24`? **with the n? without the e? what about the hyphens?** did you have a look at my regex? was it any good?

Comment: We need more details. Have a look at https://regex101.com/r/bEkrqD/1 - there are some unmatched lines, please add the expected results for `O Autor é titular de direito de uso de cadeira cativa e perpétua localizada no Estádio Jornalista Mário Filho (Maracanã), controle nº 4321` and `O autor, é titular do direito de uso de da Cadeira Cativa no Estádio
Jornalista Mário Filho (Maracanã) número de controle 4123456, fato este
que pode ser comprovado pelo documento em anexo.` Note there is no match because there are some other, unexpected words between `Cadeira` and the numbers.

Comment: Effectively, it's difficult to know clearly what you consider as valid or invalid. I would also be a bit more strict on this number. If it's like a passport number, I don't think it can be just 2 digits. In the meanwhile, you could write your regex with the `x` flag for better reading and comments, the `i` flag to be case-insensitive and the `u` flag to handle Unicode chars. I started with https://regex101.com/r/yV4gDr/4 that could help others to improve your regex. I just replaced the capturing groups by non-capturing groups and placed the spaces inside the optional words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is no more than 1 or 2 number, this regexp would capture both:

`(\bcadeiras?\b|\bnúmero\b)\s*(perpétua|cativa)?s?\s*(de|com|,)?\s*(o)?\s*(número)?\s*(de)?\s*(controle)?\s*(inicial)?\s*(de)?\s*(números?|nº)?\s*(?<NUMERO_CONTROLE_CADEIRA>\d[-\d –\.]*\d)( e (números?|nº)?(?<NUMERO_CONTROLE_CADEIRA2>\d[-\d –\.]*\d))?`

See https://regex101.com/r/88PFZw/1

Note that you have both in your numbers:

- [Unicode Character 'HYPHEN-MINUS' (U+002D)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2d/index.htm)
- [Unicode Character 'EN DASH' (U+2013)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm)
- in addition of digits, space and dot.

Comment: could include to capture "número de controle 4123456" too?

Comment: @celsowm Sure thing. I have [updated the regexp](https://regex101.com/r/88PFZw/1) accordingly.